# Changed stored procedure not recognized in ASP.NET - SQLDataSource

Tags: asp.net, debugging, stored-procedures, sqldatasource

I am working with ASP.NET and StoredProcedure. I change the stored procedure so now it returns 10 field rather than 9. I have added corresponding textbox in asp.net which gets the 10th field.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="ID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' Width="80px" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
```

But it fails, saying

> DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property
>   with the name 'ID'.

I run the stored procedure in SQL Management studio and indeed it does not return the newly  modified field. I stop and start the SQL engine and now it does spits out the new value but in my ASP.net application, it still does not recognized the new value. What is the best way to troubleshoot this? It happened to me before as well.

Adding the code where SP is called:

```
SqlConnection aConn = new 
SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConn"].ConnectionString);
SqlCommand aCommand = new SqlCommand("GetCustomer", aConn);
aCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
aCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = aID;
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(aCommand);
DataSet aCustomerDS = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(aCustomerDS);
```

My Stored Procedure is(there is nothing strange here):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetCustomer]
    @ID int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF @ID = 0
BEGIN    
SELECT  ID,
    [this field] as thisfield,
       [that field] as thatfield,
       [new field] as newfield
FROM MyDB.dbo.customers
ORDER BY ID DESC
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SELECT  ID,
    [this field] as thisfield,
       [that field] as thatfield,
       [new field] as newfield
FROM MyDB.dbo.Customers
WHERE ID = @ID
ORDER BY ID DESC
END
END
```

FormView is used to bind data to sdsCustomer

```
<asp:FormView ID="fvCustomer" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" DataSourceID="sdsCustomer"
            DataKeyNames="ID" OnPreRender="OnfvCustomer_PreRender">
```

Comment: Can you post the sproc (at least the select portion) and the datasource definitions?

Comment: Good additions but just the conn isn't sufficient.  Need the SQL for the data being returned and the form's data source that you're presumably binding to aCustomerDS.

Comment: updated with SP but there is nothing strange there.

Comment: Still not seeing the datasource definition you're binding to your controls, though.

Comment: Added that part (to the end). The very first piece of code is inside this formview.

Comment: The datasource - not the form view.  sdsCustomer - that thing marked with "DataSourceID" inside the formview.

Comment: You put me in the right direction. I see there is an anomaly here. Forview DataSource point to a different SP not the one that is created on the fly. But I am sure that is the one that populates the formview when records are renewed. Do you think this *could* be a bug in the code? Meaning it works because the first sql and formview sql has most of the field overlapped except the new added field. Need furhter investigation.

Comment: I dunno. You still haven't posted the actual code requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the data source itself to reflect the results coming out.

Comment: The datasource is generated on the fly in C# code. It is always updated when I run the application + the call of storedprocedure and the number of parameters has not changed, only inside of SP.

Comment: You mean that AutoGenerateColumns is turned on?

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best way to troubleshoot this?

What's the source for your stored proc look like?

Set a breakpoint on the line that runs the query. Examine the results that are returned and make sure that your ID column is, in fact, present.

Alternatively, fire up the SQL Profiler and ensure that:

1. The ID column is present in the result set when the procedure is called with the same parameter values that the application is using,
2. Your proc is only returning one result set.
3. Make sure you've included the line

   set nocount on;

in your procedure.

If the procedure is unintentionally returning multiple result sets (which will happen if you leave out the `set nocount` statement) your data source may not contain what you're expecting.

Comment: I am there but do you know where data is stored in DataSet, can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

My answer : It was complicated.

The FormView1 was bound to two storedprocedure: 1) usuing SQLDataSource 2) using SQLDataSource on the fly

If I would change the one that is created on the fly, ASP would give me error that the new field is not recognized by the formview. To get rid of this error, I modify the original SQLDataSource that was bound to formview and added that field, this get rid of the error. So basically this is Microsoft bug. It looks look at a different stored procecedure and I am fillwing the formview with a different stored procedure, if the field in the two stored procedure do not match I get a very misleading error because ID is indeed in the stored procedure but not in the one that is tied with the formview. Below is a diagram of the bug.

[image]